# Intel VEX prefix, L bit value does not behave according to docs

Tags: assembly, x86, avx, machine-code, illegal-instruction

Intel instruction set reference gives us **addsd** instruction:

```
VEX.NDS.LIG.F2.0F.WIG 58 /r
VADDSD xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m64
```

As we can see L bit is ignored (can be either 0 or 1).

Machine code of **addsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm0**: `0xC4, 0xE1, 0x7B, 0x58, 0xC0`

```
C4 - indicates 3-byte VEX prefix
E1 - R = 1; X = 1; B = 1; m-mmmm = 1 (implied 0F escape)
7B - W = 0; vvvv = 1111 (xmm0); L = 0; pp = 11 (implied F2 prefix)
58 - opcode byte
C0 - mod-rm byte
```

Let's test:

```
void exec(Byte* code, int size)
{
    Byte* buf = (Byte*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    memcpy(buf, code, size);

    buf[size] = 0xC3;

    ((void (*)())buf)();

    VirtualFree(buf, 4096, MEM_DECOMMIT);
}

void f()
{
    Byte code[] = { 0xC4, 0xE1, 0x7B, 0x58, 0xC0 };

    exec(code, sizeof(code));
}
```

Fine, also visual studio disassembler recognizes the instruction.

However when I change **L bit to 1** (0x7B is replaced by 0x7F) disassembler does not recognize the instruction and Invalid Instruction exception is generated. Does it mean that L bit must always be 0 despite Intel manual?

Comment: If you want to test for byte sequences being valid instructions, it's a lot easier to just put them in a `.asm` and assemble it, like `_start: db 0xC4, 0xE1, 0x7B, 0x58, 0xC0`.  Then you just assemble and run it.  More importantly, disassemblers will happily operate on your bytes, because they're in a part of your object file that's supposed to hold code.  It looks like your method works fine; it's just overcomplicated.

Comment: With Visual C++, you could also use `#pragma code_seg(".text")` and `unsigned char const __declspec(allocate(".text")) code[] = { 0xC4, 0xE1, 0x7B, 0x58, 0xC0, 0xC3 };`  With GCC you can just use `unsigned char const __attribute__((section(".text"))) code[] = { 0xC4, 0xE1, 0x7B, 0x58, 0xC0, 0xC3 };`.

Comment: @PeterCordes  : Do you know if the `illegal-instruction` tag was undergoing burnination. I notice that @tkausl removed it from all the questions. I know you have added it to questions in the past.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Wondered the same thing.  IDK if it was adding much value, but it didn't seem like a problematic tag to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't think it was either, although it may have lacked a tag wiki description. I just happened to wonder why all of a sudden a pile of questions moved to recently active.

Comment: @tkausl: Why did you remove the `illegal-instruction` tag from every question without first asking on meta about doing so?  (Or did you?  I searched but didn't find any hits).  We should probably make a chat instead of using comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like LIG doesn't really mean the L bit is ignored; **that part of the manual is wrong**.  In practice it's actually a synonym for `.LZ` or `.128` and means L must be 0.

You're right that Intel's insn ref manual (Section 3.1.1.2 (*Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table (Instructions with VEX prefix)* of volume 2 of the x86 manuals) contradicts observed behaviour:

> If VEX.LIG is present in the opcode column: The VEX.L value is
>   ignored. This generally applies to VEX-encoded scalar SIMD
>   floating-point instructions.

However, it also contradicts other documentation in the same manual.  Intel's manuals do have occasional mistakes. :( I think you can report bugs on Intel's forum.

---

Presumably Intel changed their mind about ignoring the bit, and decided to keep the L=1 encoding of scalar opcodes reserved, but forgot to update the docs for what VEX.LIG means in the insn-encoding section.

They publish future-extensions updates to the insn set reference manual before they become official, probably before every detail of hardware design is finalized.  (The current future-extensions supplemental pdf describes AVX512 instructions (found in KNL), and a few other extensions that aren't in the official manual yet, or available in any commercially-available silicon AFAIK.)  (Links to Intel's docs page, and tons of other stuff, in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

---

**From Intel's insn ref manual, Fig2-9 VEX bit fields**:

> L: Vector Length
>
> 1. scalar or 128-bit vector
> 2. 256-bit vector

Section 2.3.6.2 explains the same thing.

---

Note that some BMI1/2 instructions use VEX encodings, also with L=0.  It looks like they indicate it with `.Lz`:   `VEX.NDS.LZ.0F38.W0 F2 /r` is 
`ANDN r32a, r32b, r/m32`.

Comment: You talked about running asm file. Do you mean that I need to export label _start and jump to that address from C program?

Comment: @igntec: no, `_start` is the default entry point for the linker.  So the code at `_start` is literally the first instruction that your program runs, no CRT startup code or anything.  On Windows, I think you can `ret` from `_start`, because the OS puts `exit` as a return address on the stack.  Set a breakpoint at `_start`, run your program, and single-step.  It's probably easier to define a `main:` in asm, though.  I'm just used to creating bare static binaries on Linux to test trivial things, so I tend to define `_start`.  related: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link.

Comment: @igntec: There's a whole [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) full of useful links that I've collected, if you want to look at more stuff :)